# Field format error: 10004-This transaction cannot be processed

Tags: paypal

Anyone else getting "Field format error: 10004-This transaction cannot be processed.. " message after Sep 29 with PayPal Website payments?

Comment: The question is on hold so I can't add an answer. Paypal rep. confirmed it is a known issue. Hope they will fix it soon.

Comment: @Yossi did you got any answer fom Paypal? We are facing the same issue and I can't find the cause

Comment: 3 years later I am now getting this same error in my old opencart paypal advanced checkout on multiple different sites....  Any insight?  Was this on PayPal's side or was it fixable?

Answer (score 0):

The error started for us on September 26th.  We are still receiving payments but have had a handful of customers encounter this error.

Comment: Thank you John
Do you know what is common among all these customers who are getting "Field format error: 10004 ?

Comment: Haven't seen the error since October 1st.  Could not find any commonalities with those affected.  From other comments, looks like maybe it was PayPal?